# Get Category image in with getChildrenCategories->getImageUrl (MAGENTO)

Tags: php, magento

I use this `$categories` through out the page

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
    ->addIsActiveFilter()
    ->addAttributeToSort('position'); 

foreach($categories as $cat) {$children=$cat->getChildrenCategories();}
```

Option 1

```
//option 1 

$children  = $category->getChildren();
foreach(explode(',', $children) as $child):
$sub = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child);

$sub->getName() // this return ok, name show up
$sub->getImageUrl() // this return ok, image show up
```

Option 2 works but can't get image url for some reason.

```
//option 2 
$children  = $category->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($children as $sub):

$sub->getName() // this return ok, name show up
$sub->getImageUrl() // this return empty, image NOT show up so is other attribute beside name.
```

can someone explain the difference? and how would i go about it with opt 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, When we are using  `getChildrenCategories()` function  only few fields has been retrieve from category field collection ->`url_key,name,all_children,is_anchor`.

you can see that on class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category`.So if want tget image url from function then just add `addAttributeToFilter('image')`

```
  $collection = $category->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
    ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
    ->joinUrlRewrite()
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
->addAttributeToSelect('image');


foreach($category as $eachChildCat){

if ($image = $eachChildCat->getImage()) {
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
    }
}
```

**$eachChildCat->getImage() not work then use $eachChildCat->getResource()->getImage()**

Comment: It will work only if you clear loaded collection, add attribute to select and load collection again: $category->getChildrenCategories()->clear()->addAttributeToSelect('image_url')->load(); Anyway, it's better approach than mine ;]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really frustrated, if I add another ->load it increase my load time by a whole 2 second(no cached).

Comment: wait. igive you solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `getModel()` try to call `getSingleton()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get image url in second option, you have to load category:

```
$subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub->getId());
$imageUrl = $subcategory->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

if using magento 2

I tried following so that it does not affect performance and you need to call the category model seprately

Open in root of magento 2.2

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php

On line750ish

Add

```
->addAttributeToSelect(
    'image'
)
```

or replace function

```
 /**
     * Return child categories
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function getChildrenCategories($category)
    {
        $collection = $category->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
            'url_key'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'image'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'all_children'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'is_anchor'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'is_active',
            1
        )->addIdFilter(
            $category->getChildren()
        )->setOrder(
            'position',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
        )->joinUrlRewrite();

        return $collection;
    }
```